# Git: How to remove commit's parent commit

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rewrite-history

I performed some cleanups in a repository with [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) and ended with some unwanted artifacts as a result. At some point in the repo history, I have the following setting:

```
... -> A -> B -> C -> ... -> X -> Y -> Z -> ... -> HEAD/master
             \                   /
               P -> Q ----------

(both X and Q are Y's parents)
```

I turns out that P and Q are now both **empty** and **detached** commits. Y is a merge commit which is also empty (no changes, just have an additional parent). Between C and X there are many commits (including branches and merges, none related to the P->Q "branch".

I wanted to delete the P->Q commits and links altogether since they contains no changes at all. Something like the following as result:

```
... -> A -> B -> C -> ... -> X -> Y -> Z -> ... -> HEAD/master
```

I've googled about editing parents with rebase, replace, filter-branch but I'm having a hard time to get this right (I'm a novice git user).

Comment: Possibly just running `git rebase X` will remote the merge commit for you.

Comment: Rebase seemed to process some files and end without errors, but there was no changes in the tree.

Comment: 'git rebase --onto X Z' should do the trick but will remove Y because it's empty merge commit.

Comment: I think that did the trick. Thanks Philippe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `git rebase --onto X Z` to re-apply Z onto X (skipping y).